# Create a new variable product with its attributes for variations in WooCommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, methods, product, taxonomy-terms

The attributes pa_at-cor and pa_at-tamanho already exists (I inspected it in front end) I'm creating a new variable product and I'd like to regard those attributes to it but I can't, I saw so many posts regarding this but they most regards to creating a new attribute or just creating the variation of a already created variable product with attributes, I tried to use update_post_meta regarding attributes data, I tried so many combination of codes and even removing "pa" from taxonomy, but I didn't managed it

```
function go_cadastro_vo_products(){
    $product = new WC_Product_Variable();
    $product->set_name( 'Variable Product Example 3' );
    $product->set_description( 'This is a variable product example.' );
    $product->set_status( 'publish' );
    $product->set_catalog_visibility( 'visible' );

    // Set custom attributes
    $attributes = array(
        'pa_at-cor' => array(
            'name'         => 'pa_at-cor',
            'value'        => '',
            'position'     => 1,
            'visible'   => 1,
            'variation' => 1,
            'taxonomy'  => 1,
        ),
        'pa_at-tamanho' => array(
            'name'         => 'pa_at-tamanho',
            'value'        => '',
            'position'     => 2,
            'visible'   => 1,
            'variation' => 1,
            'taxonomy'  => 1,
        ),
    );

    $product->set_attributes($attributes);

    // Save the product
    $product_id = $product->save();

    // Set attribute values using wp_set_object_terms
    wp_set_object_terms($product_id, 'Azul', 'pa_at-cor');
    wp_set_object_terms($product_id, 'GG', 'pa_at-tamanho');


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will work based on your product attribute data, assuming that both product attributes already exist and for each the associated terms.

> You can use either term names, term slugs or term Ids as [`wp_set_object_terms()` WordPress function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_set_object_terms/) can handle any of them.

Try the following tested and working code:

```php
// Define your product attributes: Array of taxonomiy => term names (array) pairs
$attr_data  = array(
    'pa_at-cor'     => array('Azul'),
    'pa_at-tamanho' => array('GG'),
);

// Get an empty instance of the WC_Product_Variable Object
$product = new WC_Product_Variable();

$product->set_name( 'Variable Product 20' );
$product->set_description( 'This the variable product description…' );
$product->set_status('publish');
$product->set_catalog_visibility('visible');

$attributes = array(); // Initializing
$position   = $attr_id = 0; // Initializing

// Loop through product attribute data
foreach ($attr_data as $taxonomy => $terms ) {
    $attr_id++;
    // Get an empty instance of the WC_Product_Attribute Object
    $attribute = new WC_Product_Attribute(); 
    $attribute->set_id($attr_id);
    $attribute->set_name($taxonomy);
    $attribute->set_position($position);
    $attribute->set_visible(1);
    $attribute->set_variation(1);
    $attributes[$taxonomy] = $attribute;
    $position++;
}
$product->set_attributes($attributes);
$product_id = $product->save(); // Save product that returns the product ID

// Then Loop again through the defined product attribute data (2nd loop)
foreach ($attr_data as $taxonomy => $terms ) {
    // For each attribute, assign the desired terms to the product
    wp_set_object_terms( $product_id, $terms, $taxonomy, true );
}
```

I have tested the code with this related product attributes data:

```php
$attr_data  = array(
    'pa_size'  => array('Blue', 'Gray'),
    'pa_color' => array('Large', 'Small'),
);
```

From existing product attributes and related terms:

[image]

and I created successfully a variable product with its product attributes for variations:

[image]

Comment: I resolved it before I see your post, but my solution was the same I was avoiding to use new WC_Product_Attribute(); thinking it would rewrite my existing attribute